# Is there a way to make a default roaming profile using Server 2008 on a 2003 domain?

Tags: terminal, windows-server-2008, roaming-profiles

This domain uses roaming profiles for these specific users. I want to have files in the profile of every profile created. On a regular machine, I would put it in the All users directory. I can’t do that here because it is a roaming profile. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Script it in Group Policy.  If I'm not mistaken, group policy logon scripts execute as the system account - this allows you to put in a script that copies files to the all users folder without serious concerns about permissions.  Reference the %allusersprofile% environment variable when creating the script to copy files - for example:

copy "\server\share\path\to\file to\copy*.*" "%allusersprofile%\desktop"